Extract Primary Key column name and value on update through trigger
I am trying to create a trigger which can provide me the primary key name and value, and insert it into another table. I want to use the other table to update cache.
below is my code snippet
    create or replace TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_TGR AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON EMPLOYEE 

REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW

FOR EACH ROW

    DECLARE 

        tableName VARCHAR2(40);

        actionType VARCHAR2(1);

        identifierColumn VARCHAR2(40);

        identifierValue VARCHAR2(650);

        sql_statement VARCHAR2(200);
 
    BEGIN
 
        -- SET TABLE NAME
        tableName := 'EMPLOYEE';

        -- GET PRIMARY KEY OF TABLE
        SELECT cols.column_name INTO identifierColumn FROM all_constraints cons 
        JOIN all_cons_columns cols ON cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name 
        WHERE cons.table_name=tableName AND cons.constraint_type = 'P' AND ROWNUM =1;
 
        -- CHECK ACTION TYPE (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE)

        IF DELETING THEN
            actionType := 'D';
        ELSIF UPDATING THEN
            actionType := 'U';
        ELSE
            actionType := 'I';
        END IF;
 
        IF actionType = 'U' THEN
            
            sql_statement:= 'SELECT :1.' || identifierColumn || 'FROM EMPLOYEE';

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sql_statement);

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_statement INTO identifierValue USING :OLD;
 
            IF :OLD.identifierColumn != :NEW.NAME THEN

                PROC_INSERT_IN_AUDIT (tableName, :OLD.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, :OLD.LAST_UPDATE_BY, 'Y', actionType, identifierColumn, identifierValue, 'NAME', :OLD.NAME, :NEW.NAME);

            END IF;
 
            IF :OLD.URI != :NEW.URI THEN

                PROC_INSERT_IN_AUDIT (tableName, :OLD.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, :OLD.LAST_UPDATE_BY, 'Y', actionType, identifierColumn, identifierValue, 'URI', :OLD.URI, :NEW.URI);

            END IF;
 
            IF :OLD.SCENARIO_CODE != :NEW.SCENARIO_CODE THEN

                PROC_INSERT_IN_AUDIT (tableName, :OLD.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, :OLD.LAST_UPDATE_BY, 'Y', actionType, identifierColumn, identifierValue, 'SCENARIO_CODE', :OLD.SCENARIO_CODE, :NEW.SCENARIO_CODE);

            END IF;
 
            IF :OLD.USE_CASE_CODE != :NEW.USE_CASE_CODE THEN

                PROC_INSERT_IN_AUDIT (tableName, :OLD.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, :OLD.LAST_UPDATE_BY, 'Y', actionType, identifierColumn, identifierValue, 'SCENARIO_CODE', :OLD.USE_CASE_CODE, :NEW.USE_CASE_CODE);

            END IF;
 
        ELSIF actionType = 'D' THEN

            -- identifierValue:= :OLD.identifierColumn;

            PROC_INSERT_IN_AUDIT (tableName, :OLD.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, :OLD.LAST_UPDATE_BY, 'Y', actionType, identifierColumn, identifierValue, NULL, NULL, NULL);
 
        ELSE

            -- identifierValue:= :NEW.identifierColumn;

            PROC_INSERT_IN_AUDIT (tableName, :NEW.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, :NEW.LAST_UPDATE_BY, 'Y', actionType, identifierColumn, identifierValue, NULL, NULL, NULL);
 
        END IF;
 
    END EMPLOYEE_TRIGGER;

I am basically trying to extract the primary key and primary key value from the LOOP or ROW.
I tried to Extract the value from :OLD and :NEW but it doesn't allow to extract those values I get an error
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD

Please help me with the extraction of primary key and primary Value from ROW.

Why are you selecting the row again from the employee table? You've already got the row in the :OLD record. Also, why are you dynamically selecting the primary key column for the employee table? Surely it doesn't change? Why not just hardcode it?

That part to get the primary key is dynamic, I'm assuming because you want to reuse that code for many triggers. This will come at a very high performance cost. You're much better off creating code to generate the individual trigger code.

@Boneist I wanted to use this code on multiple table, Since I have to update cache on multiple tables.

@KoenLostrie yes you are right
I understand the performance impact, but is there a way to achieve this ?

Yes, you can write code that generates a trigger.

Have you googled "oracle generate trigger script" ? I got this hit. It should guide you in the right direction.

@KoenLostrie I think that wont help, I need to identify the primary of the record updated. Not generate a new primary key. My requirement it on any UPDATE DELETE or INSERT I should know the primary key of the record updated

I know that. The idea is that you get the primary key column name in the code that generates the trigger so every trigger has the correct primary key reference. The link above shows a basic script to generate a trigger. In your case You'd have to add some code to get the primary key column.
Start by writing a trigger for table for which you know what the pk column is, then write code to generate such a trigger

@KoenLostrie Thanks for the comment,
But the script in my trigger
  SELECT cols.column_name INTO identifierColumn FROM all_constraints cons 
    JOIN all_cons_columns cols ON cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name 
    WHERE cons.table_name=tableName AND cons.constraint_type = 'P' AND ROWNUM =1;

But I cannot get the value of :NEW(generated_primary_key_column_name) or :OLD(generated_primary_key_column_name) to work So I cannot extract the primay key value.

You're missing the point. Currently you're trying to make the trigger work for any table by running that query inside of the trigger (spoiler: this is a huge performance killer that will bite you later). My suggestion is that you (1) either create the triggers by hand by putting the correct primary key column in each of them or (2) programmatically generate the trigger with the correct primary key column. Give it a try. if it fails then I'd suggest posting a new question showing exactly where you get stuck. I've written similar code a long time ago and it definitely works.
